# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused - Laravel10 / MAMP / Breeze

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-breeze, php-8.2

I create a Laravel10 project with breeze install. I log it with a MAMP db and set the .env DB variable. That's seams to come from breeze but there are too much vendor frames to share it here. Am I naming my database wrong ?

```
.env

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=project_laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

When I do `php artisan migrate`, the DB successfully update with correct table.
But when I try to sign in or sign up, He send me a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` error specified with `SELECT count(*) AS aggregate FROM users WHERE email = email@email.com`

```php
config/database.php

'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

I already try as much solution as I found on forum but nothing change, I try to change the Document root on MAMP, to set `'unix_socket'` on database.php or create a .env variable but nothing change.

Comment: if the problem is solved you mark the answer that helped as accepted (event if that's yours -> that's OK). You may need to wait a moment before SO allows you to accept the answer, but that's the proper way of marking problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the port into the `DB_HOST` as "DB_HOST=127.0.0.1:8889"

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1:8889
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=project_laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: Nope, there is no change

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it, the DB_HOST need to be the name of the mysql docker container. For example: `my_project-mysql-1`